# How can we define html5?

Tags: html

In a SO question there was a comment

> HTML5 == HTML(5) + CSS3 + JavaScript.

I'm really surprised about this. Is it really acceptable to say that HTML5 equals the combination of HTML(5) + CSS3 + JavaSCript?

To say if I know html5 then I know html5, css3, javascript!

Comment: @C-link: since you voted to close I assume you realize this question isn't suited for StackOverflow. Just in case you'd like further clarification: your question can't really be answered since it doesn't have a concrete question. The answer to your question depends on how far you want to interpret the purpose of these three technologies. In a way they're linked together, but in another way they aren't. You can't give a clearcut answer.

Comment: but why that comment was upvoted?

Comment: It's a reflection of the fact that the term "HTML5" means different things to different people, and a reminder that when using the term yourself, to make clear what technology is being referred to when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5, in its self is simply a revised version of HTML.
It more or less complements the use of CSS3 and Javascript but its just plain 'ol HTML without.

Have a look here..

[HTML 5, W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp)

Some of the newer HTML5 tags can actually enhance your site's visibility in search engines by pointing out important aspects, like main articles and their authors for example.

[HTML5 Helps Improve your SEO](http://www.highervisibility.com/blog/how-html5-helps-improve-your-seo-efforts/)